# create table in sql azure/sql server 2008 from mysql

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to create table in sql azure/sql server 2008 from mysql queries.
but there is problem comes during execution of that sql query that in sql server there is need to execute transact sql query,then i tried to change that query through a converter swissconsole then table has been created but insert statement is not working through this process.
so kindly suggest me the possible solution that how can i create table from sql format queries.anyone can mail me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing details of the insert failures, I'd guess the first problem is that the resulting tables don't have clustered indiciees(sp).

That aside, take a peek at the SQL Azure Migration Wizard. it can examine your SQL and tell you changes that need to be made. http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/